# CSS Text box Scrolling Issue

Tags: html, css, text, scroll

I have a `<div>` with a lot of text in it, with the overflow set to auto because I only want a single scroll bar. When I initially code it, the scroll bar works fine and you can see all the words written within. However, once the webpage is saved and I try the scrollbar out on the saved version, it will not scroll down. What could be causing my scroll bar to no longer work?

```css
    #information {
    height: 250px;
    width: 270px;
    background: #151515;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 220px 10px 10px 200px;
    opacity: .6;
    font-family: Century Gothic;
    word-spacing: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #58D3F7;
    text-indent: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<div style="overflow: auto;" id="information">
  False text here blah blah blah
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works fine, I don't see anything wrong with it.